How to do connection pooling in a multi tenant application?
I am writing on a multi-tenant, micro-service app in C#.Net. We are having 5 services which handle the tenant-sensible data (a bunch more for global data) and we want to go live soon with 8.000 tenants, which means ~ 2500 concurrent users and ~ 1000 concurrent tenants (2.5 user per tenant). We are using the database per tenant model, because we have highly sensible data which are not allowed to be tenant-crossed persisted. We are hosting in Azure with AKS (k8s / docker) and the flexible azure db service for Postgres. We are using ngpsql with EF Core 8.0.
At the moment we are struggling hard when it comes to simulation the given user amount. We started with connection pooling without dbcontext pooling. Because every tenant has its own db, we are creating 5 (services) x 1000 (conc. tenants) = 5000 connections on the server, which immediately went to the error of max. connections. We raised that to a certain amount (default is 100, but we tried even a few thousands) but still it seemed to be doomed. (Even if we got this to 5K, the Azure max would be 5K, so that means with growing user amount next year, we would be failing again).
We then disabled the connection pooling (pooling=false in the conString) and we see positive results. But now in performance tests something is killing us. With 100-200 users the response time is fine (10-50ms) but with growing users the database seem to be doomed and we are talking about 2-5 seconds for a bunch of very simple queries. We took the max amount of power of the azure server (max iops, max CPU, max mem) to test, but we don't see any significant changes. It feels like without connection pooling the overhead of the handshake and creating a connection is too much to handle.
We tried the solution here with the DataSourceRegistry (https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/4523) but again the amount of connections in the pool is back to 5K, which is again not able to handle.
What can I try next?

something is killing us. because you disabled connection pooling. That didn't fix anything. The max connection error is telling you there are too many connections already. You can increase the limit but you'll still need a different connection for each set of credentials. Disabling pooling means everything now has to create a new connection.

The question is a bit unclear too. What do 5K connections refer to? Does a single service instance have 5K connections in the connection pool? Or are there 5K concurrent connections to a single database? Did a single service instance had to server 5K tenants in the 5 minutes idle time of a pooled connection? 5K active connections would suggest bugs in the code too. Pooled connections aren't active, which is why the default is 100. You don't need a lot of pooled connections if the code disposes connections as soon as possible.

The easy way to reduce the number of pooled connections is to use more service instances, each serving a specific set of tenants. A "micro"service serving 5K tenants isn't very micro any more. Instead of disabling pooling you can decrease the idle timeout, thus killing connections sooner, but that won't help if all tenants make requests all the time.

"It feels like without connection pooling the overhead of the handshake and creating a connection is too much to handle."  It seems like quite a leap to this conclusion.  While that is certainly a possibility, there are other possibilities as well and you haven't shown any evidence to indicate that this the likeliest one.

With an architecture of one database per tenant, you won't be able to do effective connection pooling.
You need a different architecture, for example:

all tenants share the same table and you use row-level security

all tenants share one database, and each has its own schema



Or use multiple service instances to handle fewer tenants at a time. 5K pooled connections means a single service had to handle 5K different tenants within the default 5 min idle time. That's a lot, and not really "micro". This looks like a can't-have-all-three triangle between Cost, Performance and Security

Is schema based multi tenancy a thing in EF Core? I read about this and a lot of warnings for this are out there

I have no idea about Entity Framework. Doing it with schemas is a problem if you have lots of tenants, but so is tons of databases in a single cluster.
